# Error related to shft+enter and enter with Jquery

Tags: jquery

When I type 'hello??' in text area (id = add_new_comment) it inserts **hellojQuery1704879437133033947_1333718592556??** in database. What's the problem with the code? Thanks in Advance

```
    $('#add_new_comment').live('keyup',function (event) {

            /*shft+enter for new line*/

        if (event.keyCode == 13 && event.shiftKey) {
           $(this).val($(this).val()+"\n");

           return false;   
        }else if(event.keyCode == 13){
            /*code to be inserted in db*/
        }
    });
```

Database code (ie. model in codeigniter)

```
function add_new_comment($comment, $store_id, $comment_source,$user_id) {
        $data = array(
            'comment' => $comment // comment to be inserted. This contains the text of textarea.
            'source_id' => $store_id,
            'comment_source' => $comment_source,
            'from_user_id' => $user_id
        );
        $result = $this->db->insert(COMMENTS, $data);

        return $this->db->insert_id(); 
    }
```

js script (actual code):

```
$('#add_new_comment').live('keyup',function (event) {
               if (event.keyCode == 13 && event.shiftKey) {
                   $(this).val($(this).val()+"\n");

                   return false;   
               }else if(event.keyCode == 13){

                   var store_id = "";

                   store_id = $('.c_store_comment').attr('id');

                   var new_comment = $.trim($(this).val());

                   $.ajax({
                    type:'post',
                    url:path to controller,
                    data:'comment='+new_comment+'&store_id='+store_id,
                    dataType:'json',
                    success:function(vals){
                        $.each(vals,function(i,values){
                            switch (i) {
                                    case 'error':
                                        alert('Sorry Something went Wrong');
                                    break;

                                    case 'success':
                                        var comment_div = '<div class="col1_comment2_row"><div class="col1_comment2_row_tilte">'+$('.user_name').html()+'</div>';
                                        comment_div += '<div class="col1_comment2_row_img"><a href="#nodo"><img class="delete_comment" id="'+values[1]+'" src="/images/delete_comment.png"></a> </div>';
                                        comment_div += '<div class="col1_comment2_row_cooment">'+values[0]+' </div></div>';


                                        $('.c_store_comment .scroll_container').append(comment_div);
                                        $('#add_new_comment').val('');

                                    break;
                                }                   
                        });
                    }
                   });         
               }
            });
```

Comment: Funny Chad!
Don't you need his email password too? :)

Comment: is it because the string contains "??" in data attribute of ajax? ie. data:'comment='+new_comment+'&store_id='+store_id

Comment: shall escaping the '?' in the string help in this case??

Comment: @user1257221, do you mean the problem only occurs when you enter question marks in the text area?

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi, yes it happens only when the text contains '?'.

Comment: @skafandri What are you talking about? How can I check the code without seeing the code?
@user1257221 try changing `data:'comment='+new_comment+'&store_id='+store_id,` to `data: { comment: new_comment, store_id: store_id },` so that jQuery will handle url encoding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your comments, the problem only occurs when question mark characters are present in the comment's text.

These characters are indeed reserved in URLs (they mark the start of the query string). In addition, jQuery doesn't escape them because you're passing a string in the `data` option to `$.ajax()` instead of an object, so no processing is performed.

I cannot explain why what looks like the jQuery expando property ends up being posted to the server, though, and a quick glance through the source code didn't reveal anything obvious. However, a sure way to work around the problem would be to pass an object in the `data` option instead of a string:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "path/to/controller",
    data: {
        comment: new_comment,
        store_id: store_id
    },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(vals) {
        // ...
    }
});
```

That way, jQuery will automatically escape the reserved characters in your data, and your problem should go away.

Comment: Apparently my post of this answer in comments wasn't good enough for him to try :P

Answer (score -1):

```
$('#add_new_comment').live('keyup',function (event) {

        /*shft+enter for new line*/

    if (event.keyCode == 13 && event.shiftKey) {
       $(event.currentTarget).val($(event.currentTarget).val()+"\n");

       return false;   
    }else if(event.keyCode == 13){
        /*code to be inserted in db*/
    }
});
```

Comment: `this` is correctly bound to the event target by `live()`, there is no need to use `currentTarget`. I'm also afraid your answer doesn't address the questioner's problem in the first place.